# How can I get the symmetric encryption key used by SSH?

Tags: encryption, openssh

I'm looking into a Wireshark trace made by myself, and I wanted to see what the client sent to the server and what the server replied in the encrypted application data stream. While I see what method was used for encryption (ChaCha), I obviously can't see the symmetric encryption key, which was negotiated using Diffie Hellman.

Is there an option for `ssh` or `sshd` to print or log the secret key used in the symmetric cipher?

Answer (score 0):

No. You would have to recompile `openssh` to get this information from the client. All the keys are derived in [kex.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/kex.c#L926).

Note that there are 6 of them derived from the shared secret, 2 IV, 2 for encryption and 2 for MAC (different for both directions).